# Will calling the kernal32 IsDebuggerPresent function cause antivirus programs to flag my app?

Tags: c#, winforms, antivirus, kernel32

I am writing a c# desktop application that calls IsDebuggerPresent and if it is my app exits. I read in following article that antivirus programs look for this function as an indicator of malware:
https://www.alienvault.com/open-threat-exchange/blog/your-malware-shall-not-fool-us-with-those-anti-analysis-tricks

Will this function get my app flagged by antivirus programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is highly unlikely that your program will be flagged.

The article was talking about the native version of the call and that call was using a extremely non-standard way of calling to try and avoid detection, not the managed version.

However, I doubt you will find any benefit of doing this in your program, it will not stop people at all from analyzing your program at all. People can just put a breakpoint on the call to `IsDebuggerPresent` and then just skip over the `if` check. The only thing you are likely to cause by adding this check is more headaches for yourself when you go to try and solve problems in your code.

Comment: "will not stop people at all" - especially true for C#/.Net code... Removing call and recompiling is not exactly rocket science (even for obfuscated code).

Answer (score 1):

The only way to know is to test.  I know that the enterprise version of Symantec doesn't mind at all for the managed version.

Note that that call does not facilitate virus activity on a system.  It merely helps the virus annoy an analyst in an AV lab for up to a day.  There is no reason to look for it in the wild as a sign of a virus.